# Behat and Mink: assert page ignore trailing slash

Tags: php, behat, mink

I want to write simple test like:

```
Given I am on "/"
Then I should be on "/login"
```

I want ignore trailing slash on assertion, so, if user redirected to `/login/`, assertion should not fail.

Now it fail. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to override the method for the *I should be on* step and remove the last / if needed|found.